# My new website registration error

Tags: user-registration

Hello awesome community!

I have a new website and bought a LMS theme from thimpress. I followed a tutorial on YouTube and now my registration and login is not working properly. Is there any way I can ask for a volunteer for a few hours please? I have been trying for a few weeks now.

Message me at pepper_perspective on reddit!
Thank you!

Comment: Or send me a message here please!

Comment: Welcome :) This forum works by you describing as carefully and as detailed as possibly, what you are trying to do and the problems you face - you will need to share details of your website, theme and plugins and possibly code or screen grabs - in order that people can help you here.

Comment: Okay! So basically I signup up for wordpress through HostGator and bought a LMS from thimpress. Most of the functions were working on the site until it came to the registration/login part. For some reason it keeps giving me an error or a captcha error. Now I uninstalled all of my plugins and am restarting it. Basically I want to have a section where someone can:
- login as a student
- sign up for a student
- login as an instructor
- sign up to become an instructor
I used the Eduma theme - and still, they’re not able to log into my wordpress website even tho HostGator went thru it with me.

Comment: I gave them my wordpress login, but I don’t know why Thimpress cannot login. 
So, I’m hoping someone can support me on this… I can provide the login information if need be to check it out.

Comment: Please DO NOT provide sensitive security information here. This really sounds like an issue you need to be discussing with either themeforest or your hosting company.

Comment: No I won’t provide my password here or information. I checked with both - but they do not provide those services.

Comment: Hi, Pepper, welcome to WPSE. I think what @Q Studio is trying to convey is that your questions is not aligned with StackExchange purpose and rules. Please review the following resources : [code of conduct](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/conduct), [how to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [What Topics Can I Ask here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the help center: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Ah ok, thank you!